# How to add user to modify SSRS report with different domain name?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I need to add user that would be able to modify SSRS reports. But the thing is that user have different domain name. 
So I get an error saying that user or group name is not recognized.
[image]

In order to add user I am going to Site Setting  - New Role Assignment and adding new one
[image]
What am I missing?

Comment: Stupid question but can you log on with that user?

Comment: Going to Site Setting, Security, New Role Assignment.
I also added picture

Comment: how did you add other users? Just with the username?

Comment: domain\username
and it worked. But now the domain is different, so I am wonder what should I do for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning permissions at wrong place. you are giving extra privilege by adding user under site setting. That user can do anything in the the report manager.

It should provide permission at Report or Folder Level

`Go To properties of report > Security > Provide Report builder access` (if user is supposed to modify in place in report manager)

http://bhushan.extreme-advice.com/user-roles-and-permissions-in-ssrs/

Also, as per your comment, check if the mentioned domain user can/supposed to connect to your report manger.

Comment: Thanks. But how would I check if the mentioned domain user can/supposed to connect to my report manger.?

Comment: Your Domain team can confirm on that. However, you can do one check like from Report Manager Server, You can do Check Name from Security tab of any folder properties (while adding).